# Finding the transformation matrix for a function from the set of complex polynomials to matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have two vector spaces, $U$ and $V$: 
\begin{align}
U&=\mathbb{C}[x]_1=\{f(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]|deg(f(x))\leq 1\}\\
V&=M_2(\mathbb{C})
\end{align}
I also have the transformation $\phi$, and I am asked to prove that $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ where $\phi(f(x))=f(\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
\end{bmatrix}$), is linear, for any $\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
\end{bmatrix} \in V$. And to find the matrix of $\phi$. Proving that it is linear is not a problem, but how would I find the transformation matrix w.r.t the standard basis for $U$ and $V$?

My attempt so far:

I know that the standard basis of $U$ is $\{1,x\}$. Also, $\phi(1)$=$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, yes?
and $\phi(x)$=$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
\end{bmatrix}$. I do not know where to go from here.

My answer is that the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & a \\
    1 & b \\
    1 & c \\
    1 & d 
\end{bmatrix}$, but this does not seem correct, since it still contains variables.

Comment: Can you find a basis for $V$?

Comment: We're given the basis for V: $\{E_{i,j}|1\leq i, j\leq 2\}$

Comment: How do you evaluate $f$ on a matrix?

Comment: Your definition of $\phi$ is problematic. For any give $f(x)\in U$, $\phi(f(x))$ must be a unique element in $V$. Need to check the statement.

Comment: user289143 - I have no idea. That was the source of at least half of my confusion. I would have thought, for example 2x+1 where x=matrix M, would be 2M+1 but i guess thats not the case, since $\phi$ maps from functions to matrices.

Comment: Jack - this was a question I was given by my prof on a practice problem sheet. I will ask for clarification.

Comment: There was an additional question that i skipped, so that may clarify the statement somehow.

Comment: I would guess that the matrix in the definition of $\phi$ is meant to be an arbitrary fixed matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re close. I’m pretty sure that the matrix in the definition of $\phi$ is meant to be an arbitrary fixed matrix, so I’d expect to see the unknown elements of this matrix appear in the solution.

Calling this fixed matrix $A$, if we have $f(x)=z+wx$, then $\phi(f)=zI+wA$, so $\phi(1)=I$, not the matrix of all ones as you determined. I think you can take it from here.